# Can you delete data from influxdb?

Tags: sql, influxdb

How do you delete data from influxdb?

The documentation shows it should be as simple as:

```
delete from foo where time < now() -1h
```

For some reason, influxdb rejects my delete statements saying "Delete queries can't have where clause that doesn't reference time"

```
select * from bootstrap where duration > 1000 and time > 14041409940s and time < now()
```

### I want to delete these 5 entries whos duration > 1000 seconds
[image]

This should be a valid sql statement, yet it fails

[image]

None of these delete statements work either

```
delete from bootstrap where duration > 3000000"

delete from bootstrap where duration > 300000"

delete from bootstrap where time = 1404140994043"

delete from bootstrap where duration > 300000 and time > 1404141054508 "

delete from bootstrap where duration > 300000 and time > 1404141054508s "

delete from bootstrap where time > 1404141054508s and duration > 300000 "

delete from bootstrap where duration > 30000 and time > 1s"
```

Documentation reference

[https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/influxql/](http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/api/query_language.html)

**Update**

Additional queries

```
delete from bootstrap where time > 1404141416824 and duration > 3000;
delete sequence_number from bootstrap where time > 1s and duration > 1000;
```

Maybe this is a bug?

https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/975
https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/84

Comment: the problem with your queries are only 2. first you cant delete from anything besides time so: <p> delete from bootstrap where duration > 3000000 <p> dont work, and with this query <p> delete from bootstrap where time > 1404141416824s <p> you say that are in seconds but that time is in miliseconds so you have to change to ms :)

Comment: Hey @spuder, the accepted answer is wrong. Any chance you can select John Clements' answer as the right one?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It appears that you can do this in influxdb 0.9. For instance, here's a query that just succeeded for me:

```
DROP SERIES FROM temperature WHERE machine='zagbar'
```

(Per generous comment by @MuratCorlu, I'm reposting my earlier comment as an answer...)

Comment: Strangely, this is now *not* working for me (slightly different query), signalling error "ERR: database not open"

Comment: Looks related (identical?) to https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/3087 , and in similar fashion, I see that while I did get an error, the deletion did actually succeed.

Comment: I fail to understand how dropping a series is an answer when the question included a timespan?

Comment: It looks to me like you could specify a timespan using a pair of WHERE clauses, no? (NB: Not trying it, don't have influxDB installed ATM).

Comment: I'm no longer employed at the place where this question has relevance, so can't test.

Answer (score 30):

With influx, you can only delete by time

For example, the following are invalid:

```
#Wrong
DELETE FROM foo WHERE time < '2014-06-30' and duration > 1000 #Can't delete if where clause has non time entity
```

This is how I was able to delete the data

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE time > '2014-06-30' and time < '2014-06-30 15:16:01'
```

Update: this worked on influx 8. Supposedly it doesn't work on influx 9

Comment: I also found out with dismay that Influxdb currently only supports time based query.

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is that this query has time:  DELETE from foo where time = '2014-06-30 12:18:00'   But that doesn't work.  I did try the time > time < and it didn't complain about time but removed ALL data that was greater than time >

Comment: Yes, I found that influx is buggy about time. You can't specify a specific time, you need to give it a range that surrounds the date you want.

Comment: Hi there, 
then I can't delete rows by "container_name", can I?

Comment: @spuder, I think you can add a link to official [documentation](http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.7/api/query_language.html#deleting-data-or-dropping-series). I suppose it may be useful for somebody who are looking for a answer.

Comment: Looks like influxdb 0.9 may allow a more flexible query language. Hopefully someone who knows more than I do can confirm this....

Comment: It appears that you can do this in influxdb 0.9. For instance, here's a query that just succeeded for me: "DROP SERIES FROM temperature WHERE machine='zagbar';" (sorry about the semicolon, it's a reflex...)

Comment: Hey @JohnClements. It worked for me. Add your comment as a new answer to make it more visible. Thanks

Comment: +1 to @JohnClements for typing an explanation for the semicolon, instead of taking the easy way out (backspace).  Now I don't feel alone.

Answer (score 17):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned [InfluxDB retention policies](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/api/influxdb-1x/dbrp/) for automatic data removal.  You can set a default retention policy and also set them on a per-database level.

From [the docs](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/query_language/database_management.html#create-retention-policies-with-create-retention-policy):

```
CREATE RETENTION POLICY <retention_policy_name> ON <database_name> DURATION <duration> REPLICATION <n> [DEFAULT]
```

Comment: To avoid any potential confusion, these retention policy links are for InfluxDB 0.9, the original poster is using InfluxDB 0.8. That said, in InfluxDB 0.9, retention policies are absolutely the first and best way to remove data, but of course they have to be pre-configured.

Comment: Also, retention policies only remove data once they are set, they do not remove previous data - however, that data is under a different retention policy and can be dropped separately since the old and new RP's data do not overlap (unless you deliberately and manually copy from one to the other)

Answer (score 10):

Because InfluxDB is a bit painful about deletes, we use a schema that has a boolean field called "ForUse", which looks like this when posting via the line protocol (v0.9):

```
your_measurement,your_tag=foo ForUse=TRUE,value=123.5 1262304000000000000
```

You can overwrite the same measurement, tag key, and time with whatever field keys you send, so we do "deletes" by setting "ForUse" to false, and letting retention policy keep the database size under control.

Since the overwrite happens seamlessly, you can retroactively add the schema too.  Noice.

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way.

Comment: Fields aren't indexed though, so this way there's a per-deleted-entry cost for each query. Which may or may not be problematic.

Comment: Lovely. I never thought that you can "delete" by inserting a "new" point by using a different boolean value! Brilliant!

Comment: This is great idea, but why do you do it with a field instead of tag?

Comment: @maxpleaner - I used a field instead of a tag because if I used a tag, it would appear as a new entry. e.g. `site=north,cabinet=3,server=2,foruse=True` and `site=north,cabinet=3,server=2,foruse=False` would be two entirely different records.

Answer (score 5):

In InfluxDB 2, InfluxQL commands like `DROP` don't exist (only InfluxQL read-only queries are supported). Instead, you need to use the [CLI](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/cli/influx/) or [REST API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/api/).

Example:

```
influx delete --bucket "MY BUCKET" --predicate '_measurement="MY_MEASUREMENT"' -o "MY ORG" --start '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' --stop '2025-12-31T23:59:00Z'
```

Comment: I had to add the token field for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Run influxdb and select the database:

```
influx -database '<database-name>'
```

Then run the query:

```
DELETE WHERE time < '2021-04-11 7:00:00'
```

Additionally, if you want to delete data from a specific `measurement`, do as follows:

```
DELETE FROM <measurement> WHERE time > '2014-06-30' and time < '2021-04-10 15:16:01'
```

Comment: There's a typo there if you're wondering why you couldn't run it ;)

Comment: @minhng99 I found the typo and fixed that ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is for InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.2

Delete works without time field too. As you can see from the series of screen shots:

1. I create a DB and and add start using it.

[image: InfluxDB create DB and use it]

2. Add some rows in it.Verify if they are added.

[image: Add rows in influxdb and print]

3. Delete all with tag 'Dev1' and verify the same.

[image: Delete all rows for tag from influxdb]

**Note**: The tag name has to be in single quotes only. Not double.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer (DROP SERIES) will work for many cases, but will not work if the records you need to delete are distributed among many time ranges and tag sets.

A more general purpose approach (albeit a slower one) is to issue the delete queries one-by-one, with the use of another programming language.

1. Query for all the records you need to delete (or use some filtering logic in your script)
2. For each of the records you want to delete:

   1. Extract the time and the tag set (ignore the fields)
   2. Format this into a query, e.g.

      ```
      DELETE FROM "things" WHERE time=123123123 AND tag1='val' AND tag2='val'
      ```

      Send each of the queries one at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete with your time field, which is a  number.

```
Delete from <measurement> where time=123456
```

will work. Remember not to give single quotes or double quotes. Its a number.

Comment: This is not true, you can specify tags in the delete query as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to already given nice answers; If you are using a version >2.* and can use its UI (usually on port 8086):

- Go to "Data"
- Select "Buckets"
- And also select the bucket you want to manage
- and give a retention time as described below;

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I am adding this commands as reference for altering retention inside of InfluxDB container in kubernetes k8s. wget is used so as container doesn't have curl and influx CLI

```
wget 'localhost:8086/query?pretty=true' --post-data="db=k8s;q=ALTER RETENTION POLICY \"default\" on \"k8s\" duration 5h shard duration 4h default" -O-
```

Verification

```
wget 'localhost:8086/query?pretty=true' --post-data="db=k8s;q=SHOW RETENTION POLICIES" -O-
```